# Can't display unicode characters from file properly

Tags: file, python-3.x

I'm writing a script which should operate on words from a number of files which have unicode characters in a form of `something\u0142somethingelse`.

I use python 3 so I suppose after reading line `\u0142` should be replaced by `'ł'` character, but it isn't. I receive `"something\u0142somethingelse"` in console.

After manually copying "bad" output from console and pasting it to: `print("something\u0142somethingelse")` it is displayed correctly.

Problematic part of the script:

```
list_of_files = ['test/stack.txt']

for file in list_of_files:
    with open(file,'r') as fp:
        for line in fp:
            print(line)
            print("something\u0142somethingelse")
```

stack.txt:

```
something\u0142somethingelse
```

Output:

```
something\u0142somethingelse
somethingłsomethingelse
```

I experimented with utf-8 encoding when opening this file and really I'm out of ideas...

Comment: If your file contains `something\u0142somethingelse`, and your program outputs `something\u0142somethingelse` ... then what is the problem, exactly?

Comment: I want \u0142 to be replaced by 'ł' character.

Comment: Well, then you'll probably have to write code to do that.

Comment: If that's the case - sure, but I thought I was missing something trivial in reading from file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do what you want with `ast.literal_eval`.  This uses the same syntax as the Python interpreter to understand literals: like `eval` but safer. So this works, for example:

```
a = 'something\\u0142somethingelse'

import ast

b = ast.literal_eval('"' + a + '"')
print '"' + a + '"'
print b
```

The output should be:

```
"something\u0142somethingelse"
somethingłsomethingelse
```

Comment: Works great in Python3 - I can get rid of my not-so-clean workaround. Thanks!